# How do I render video with rotoscope mask?

Tags: rendering, image, video, masking

When rendering my video, the background image with rotoscope doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

What I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

How it renders (imagine no mask lines):
[image]

and I notice that also, the mask lines keep shifting. Is there a way of locking them in place?

Comment: I can see you're coming to grips with this. As for your mask changing shape, even slightly, that may be because the mask's vertices are being stored as shapekeys which are relative to each other. Adjust one and those following it in the database can be affected also. I'd wager it to be why professionals recommend using a series of smaller masks - less vertices to worry about each time. My personal preference is to go for non-shapekeyed masks Their vertices are like any other object's - stay locked unless edited. They don't need keyframing either.

Comment: Using more than one mask will give you a more flexible way to deal with moving parts. Note also that some parts of the mask need to be sharp but others need feathering (see the bottom of the right arm, where motion blur will create problems if treated as a sharp shape). As for the hair... that is the nightmare for every special effects maker... as there is no one-size-fits-all kind of solution.

Answer (score 2):

The **Viewer** and  **Composite** nodes are different outputs, The **Composite** node is the one that is *rendered out* and saved to a file. The viewer is just to preview the result. Connect the composite so that it follows the same node path as the viewer, otherwise the images get processed following different transformations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this.

Comment: The render now shows the image in the background which is what I wanted - thanks a lot for that! Although some parts have the image coming through. I made sure to check the masking and it was fine. Not sure why it is inconsistent.

Comment: you need to create holes in the mask, so that the elements between the arms and the head show the next layer.

Comment: Apologies Susu. I dropped a comment here instead of above.  Have moved it. :)

Comment: I will do. But I meant that the image sometimes show over his face. I went to masking to check if I missed any mask lines and there was nothing wrong.